# Nested constants in Rust

Tags: nested, rust, constants

In Ruby, I can do this:

```rb
module Settings
  module General
    SomeSetting = "Some value"
  end
end

puts Settings::General::SomeSetting;
# => "Some value"
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Rust?

I want to have some hard-coded values and I don't want to have to declare a struct that I can then use to store the settings when I'm only ever going to create that struct once.

I've tried looking but I'm unable to find something definitive.

Is it something as simple as:

settings.rs:

```
pub mod dungeon {
    pub mod general {
        pub mod room {
            const MinSize: i32 = 6;
            const MaxSize: i32 = 10;
            const MaxNo:   i32 = 30;
        }
        pub mod lighting {
            const FovWalls: bool = true;
            const TorchRadius: i32 = 10;
        }
        pub mod monster {
            const MaxNo: i32 = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

which would allow something like

```
&settings::dungeon::general::room::MaxNo
```

Comment: @trentcl I did, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Why exactly are people down-voting this question? It's a perfectly valid question, try googling for `nesting constants in rust`, not only does nothing come up, the only thing that does is this question, which was just (relatively) adde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it something as simple as

Yes. *As your own code shows*, you can use Rust modules just like Ruby modules to add namespacing.

You can also add constants to a struct, enum, or trait:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    const BAR: i32 = 42;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Foo::BAR);
}
```